# Working with basic operations in a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $ab+ba=1$ and $a^3=a$ in a ring, show that $a^2=a$.

I understand that since $a$ is not necessarily a unit that I cannot use $a^{-1}$. That being said, I am completely stumped about how to manipulate the two assumptions to find that $a^2=a$.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does the first equation hold for some $b$ or for all $b$?

Comment: In your first formula, let $b=a$.

Comment: I don't think I can make the assumption that b=a.

Comment: I believe that it holds for some b. That being said, the problem that I was given does not clarify.

Comment: Not an assumption.  If $ab+ab = 1$ for *all* $a$ and $b$, then, *in the particular case when $a = b$*, this formula should also hold.

Comment: Counterexample to the "holds for some $b$" version: the ring is $\mathbb{R}$, $a = -1$, and $b = -1/2$.